# AutoIt @ComSpec parameters (/c, /k...)

Tags: autoit

I'm new to AutoIp and wonder what the parameters that often come with the `@ComSpec` macro mean. I couldn't find an explanation on the web. So any hint regarding `/c`, `/k` and maybe others?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`@ComSpec` is the value of `%COMSPEC%`; the specified secondary command interpreter.

(For example: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`)

A quick search on "cmd.exe arguments" should give you plenty of info.